# How to insert/update Immutable.Map of Immutable.Map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a nested Immutable.Map of Immutable.Map type defined as follows:

```
export type Data = Immutable.Map<string, Immutable.Map<string, string>>;

const nested : Data = Immutable.Map();
```

Data in the nested should look like this:

```
{
  'a': {
    'a1': 'value1',
    'a2': 'value2',
  },
  'b': {
    'b1': 'value1',
    'b2': 'value2',
  },
...
}
```

How should I insert/update a value for the `nested` variable (assume I have input like `{'a', 'a1', 'value1'}`)? I know I can do checks and create the second immutable map if it's null, but is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: There is a `setIn(pathArray, value)`, but I am not sure I understand the question

Comment: If the function in the previous comment wasn't it: Please show us with code (or pseudocode) what you want to do or/and elaborate further